# As3 - How to make phone go to sleep?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Iam developing an as3 app and what I want to do is to make a button to close(lock) or make the phone go to sleep . how can I do it?

Comment: What platform are you developing for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's no AIR way to do this. I think you'll need an ANE with some native Java code to do this.

Looks like this is the accepted way to lock the screen:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDPM.lockNow();
```

However your application is going to need admin privileges to do this so you'll have to do a few more things to get the correct permissions in your application.

See the Android documentation here for more: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

---

To create an ANE there are several tutorials on the Adobe Developer Connect eg http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html

Alternatively you could put it on our suggestion site (http://airnativeextensions.com - http://distriqt.uservoice.com) or send us an email (airnativeextensions at distriqt.com) to get one developed.

Comment: Can u please tell me if u know an ane for that and how and where do I write this code? Thanks

Comment: Updated with some ANE resources. (Note I work for distriqt)

Comment: Thanks alot Michael

Comment: One question, can I use eclipse to create this ane and is this the only code (that you provided me) that I will need ? Thanks again @Michael

Comment: Not 100% sure, it appears to work in most cases from reports I've read, however I believe there will be permission request code you'll require to implement as well. I haven't done this myself. Of course you'll need all the normal ANE code as well. Cheers

Comment: How much money do u take for making an ane? (Distriqt)

Comment: Hi, contact our team at airnativeextensions @ distriqt.com if you need some information on a custom ANE. Cheers